# Semi-permeable gas membrane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

The problem is as follows: Two ideal gases are contained adiabatically and separated by an insulating, fixed membrane that blocks the molecules of gas 2 but allows the molecules of gas 1 through(in both directions). The initial pressures, volumes, temperatures and number of molecules on each side is given. What is the equilibrium state?

The volumes remain the same, so we basically have 5 variables: The final pressures, temperatures and the net number of molecules that went through the piston. At equilibrium, the partial pressure of gas 1 must be equal on both sides, that gives 1 equation. The ideal gas law, applied to both sides gives 2 more, and the fact that the whole system's internal energy is constant gives 1 more. So I have 5 variables and only 4 equations. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I understand that, but I am not asking for a full solution, just a better understanding of the specific issue. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The assumption is that, at final equilibrium, the partial pressures of gas 1 on the two sides of the membrane are equal.